# Is there a way to search mySQL rows from bottom up and change results based on paramaters?

Tags: mysql, database, joomla, joomla-extensions

Is there a way to convert the selected content of 0 or 1 to no or yes and search from bottom of table up?

```
UPDATE #__comprofiler   
SET cb_trainingpass =   ( SELECT c_passed
FROM #__quiz_r_student_quiz
WHERE #__quiz_r_student_quiz.c_student_id = #__comprofiler.user_id)
WHERE EXISTS
  ( SELECT c_passed
FROM #__quiz_r_student_quiz
WHERE #__quiz_r_student_quiz.c_student_id = #__comprofiler.user_id);
```

As users take their test, they get a result of 0 = not-passed, or 1 = passed. I am sending this to the field cb_trainingpass and would like it to be yes (for passed) or no instead. Also, users take the test multiple times and their newest results is what I am trying to pull, unfortunately this query pulls the one at the top or the first result, never finding the newest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like

```
UPDATE #__comprofiler   
SET cb_trainingpass =   ( SELECT if(c_passed=1,'yes','no')
FROM #__quiz_r_student_quiz
WHERE #__quiz_r_student_quiz.c_student_id = #__comprofiler.user_id
order by #__quiz_r_student_quiz.YOURDATEFIELD desc)
WHERE EXISTS
  ( SELECT c_passed
FROM #__quiz_r_student_quiz
WHERE #__quiz_r_student_quiz.c_student_id = #__comprofiler.user_id);
```